# Java parse partial date

Tags: java, date, locale

Using `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` requires that all fields specified in the format be present in the input string. What I would like is some way of validating partial input strings against the same format.

For example, `Format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` and `Input="2012/01/01"` should match, and the time of day should be set to zero.

Is there any way of doing this? Currently, `SimpleDateFormat` throws an exception.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` isn't a `final` class, you could extend it (or possibly `DateFormat`).  I'm fairly sure there's no _built-in_ way to get it to behave in that fashion; you're going to have write the differences yourself.  Although, what happens if somebody only supplies '01' - do they mean January, the first of the (assumed current) month, 1:00:00, or something else?  The formatters are basically providing instructions on how to interpret the string...

Comment: The other alternative would be to start with the fullformat and then, using substring(), you remove the last character and create a new format until you find a format that matches. Kind of brutal, but very effective.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`DateUtils#parseDate(String, String[])`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) from Apache Utils.
It will allow you to pass an array of allowed formats and will try each one until something fits.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 different `SimpleDateFormat` objects, each one with a different date format, and use the first. If a parsing exception is thrown, use the other one.

Best solution IMHO is that you check the string first using regular expressions so you know which parsing format to use. Also probably you want to use grouping in the regular expression and form the date yourself (e.g. using `Calendar`) instead of parsing the string at least twice (one by regex, second by `DateFormat`).

Comment: I like the regex idea much better.  Thought of the exception thing too, but was trying to think of a clean solution that didn't rely on exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to implement the solution proposed by m0skit0, using multiple `SimpleDateFormat` you can cascade the parsing with try catch, for eg.:

```
SimpleDateFormat fullFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

String input="2012/01/01";
Date res;
try {
    res = fullFormat.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    res = shortFormat.parse(input);
}
```

Comment: Copy paste issue with your `shortFormat` =)

Comment: I already provided this answer 15+ minutes ago. Please read existing answers before answering.

Comment: @m0skit0, I read your answer but I though that illustrating with a sample code could help. Sorry for the double posting. May I edit your answer to add my example in it then delete my post ? ;)

Comment: I don't think that a code example is necessary since it looks like he's already familiar with `SimpleDateFormat` and exception catching. But if you want, feel free to do so (don't forget to add yourself on the credits!)